# Saving the clicked element and accessing it from another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i would like to do is set a click event on a particular set of DOM elements.

I would like to remember which element has  been clicked as I may need to retrieve some information from it later.

I would then like to be able to access it from another JS object if possible.

Below is what I have so far...

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<button>
      Which have you clicked on?
</button>

<script>
var listItem = {
    elementHandle: $('li'),
    instanceClicked: '',
    bindEventHandlers: function(){
        $(this.elementHandle).click(this.alertTheContent);
    },
    alertTheContent: function(){
        this.instanceClicked = $(this);
        alert(this.instanceClicked.html());
    }
}

var button = {
    elementHandle: $('button'),
    bindEventHandlers: function(){
        $(this.elementHandle).click(this.showListItemClicked);
    },
    showListItemClicked: function(){
        console.log(listItem.instanceClicked);
    }
}

listItem.bindEventHandlers();
button.bindEventHandlers();
</script>
```

I think I am close but the console log on the showClickedItem() function is returning ''. Like when I initially created the listItem object.

Please find the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/rbfaxw12/

Comment: Onclick why don't you add a class to the element. So the at in future by using that class you can get the value of that particular clicked DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `listItem` instead of `this` in the `alertTheContent` function as `this` refers to current element context which invoked the click handler i.e. `li` not `listItem`

```
alertTheContent: function(){
    listItem.instanceClicked = $(this);
    alert(listItem.instanceClicked.html());
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fzkwod92/)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `this.instanceClicked = $(this);` use `listItem.instanceClicked = $(this);`